# C - pass address of struct member to function wrong return

Tags: c, pointers, struct, mmap

## Answer :

The culprit was the keyword restrict. I missed a cast with it
Thanks

### Context

Linux.

### Question

Could you help me find a classy solution to write my parameter ?

### Why I fail

I fail because I don't want to take the normal path (see code).

### My need

Something quite classy like &(data->mmap) as a parameter to avoid creating a dummy variable like exposed in my way to circumvent the problem..

This actually doesn't work.

I have to do that way because that function may be called with different meanings.
The struct is much more complex and according to my position in the code, the second parameter is not the same.

### The code

```
struct mystruct {
 char * mmap;
}
void test(mystruct * _input, char * my_char){

 int fd;
 ...
 // WORKS FINE. THE ADDRESS IS PRINTED IN mySecondFunction CORRECTLY.
 // THAT IS THE OBVIOUS WAY
 //_input->_mmap = (char*)mmap( 0 , 128 , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED , fd , 0 );

 // FAILS TO PRINT THE RIGHT ADDRESS IN mySecondFunction
  my_char = (char*)mmap( 0 , 128 , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED , fd , 0 );
 ...

 printf("in function address %p\n", my_char);

}
void mySecondFunction(mystruct * data){

 test(data, data->mmap);
 printf("data->mmap %p\n",data->mmap);

}
int main(void){

 mystruct test;

 mySecondFunction(&test);


 return 0;
}
```

### My way to deal with this situation

```
void test(mystruct * _input, char ** my_char){

   ...
   * my_char = (char*)mmap( 0 , 128 , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED , fd , 0 );
   ...
}
void mySecondFunction(mystruct * data){

 char * _tmp;
 // This is where i would like something like &data->mmap to replace &_tmp in order to get the right address directly.
 test(data, &_tmp);
 data->mmap = tmp;
 printf("data->mmap %p\n",data->mmap);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: what's stopping you from doing test(data, &(data->mmap)) in your way of dealing with it?

Comment: This looks like C code, not C++.

Comment: Is this C or C++? What's wrong with the "obvious" way (which seems better to me, since the function only needs one parameter)? In any case, the second one needs to pass a pointer, `&data->mmap`; in C++, the first will work if you change the parameter type to `char*&`.

Comment: That part is C'ish that is right. For an unknown reason, &(data->mmap) will not keep the pointer value back in mySecondFunction !!

Comment: This is a bizarre question. Something tells me you aren't telling us everything.

Comment: I do and I am stuck with it ! No kidding. Some other irrelevant things happen before (not related to that member). Let me update the question

Answer (score 2):

In `test`, you set the local `my_char` variable to the address you get from `mmap`. This doesn't affect the `_tmp` variable in `main`.

If you want to change the variable you pass to the function you have to instead pass a pointer to it, like this:

```
void test(mystruct * _input, char ** my_char){
   *my_char = (vhar*)mmap(...);
}

test(data, &data->mmap);
```

Comment: You'll also need to print it out with a  printf("data->mmap %p\n",&(data->mmap));

Comment: The problem was something else : I use the restrict keyword. Removing it corrected the whole problem.. dumb.. Thanks ! +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete fix:

```
void test(mystruct * _input, char ** my_char){
    //Update the reference that was passed
    *my_char = (char*)mmap( 0 , 128 , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED , fd , 0 );

    printf("in function address %p\n", my_char);
}

void mySecondFunction(mystruct * data){
    test(data, &(data->mmap));  // Pass by reference
    printf("data->mmap %p\n",&(data->mmap)); // Prints address of data->mmap
}
```

Comment: The problem was something else : I use the restrict keyword. Removing it corrected the whole problem.. dumb.. Thanks ! +1